# Blinking screen in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, radeon, amd-processor, gpu-driver

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, the screen of my laptops blinks persistently (it turns on and off all the time). I'm not versed at linux at all, but I've searched a lot of forums and tried different things without success (For instance, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)).

I had ubuntu 12.04 LTS and everything worked just fine. I did an upgrade to 14.04 and everything worked fine at the begginig but, after the first automatic update -through the software updater- the problem started. Please help!

Some relevant video-card info:

```
lspci  | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690M [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270]
```